# Android - set textview dynamically in row wise

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, textview

I have to create textview with json dynamically. For now I successfully[Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unUyw.png) create but not in proper way.

Like this image but not able to create. I done like that, [Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdaEv.png)

Here is xml code --

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/layout_top_search"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>
```

Here is java code

```
try {
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean status = object.getBoolean("status");
                if (status) {
                    JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("topsearches");
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                        final TextView textView;

                        JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
                        String keyword = jsonObject.getString("search-keyord");
                        String cat_id = jsonObject.getString("category_id");
                        textView = new TextView(getActivity());
                        textView.setText(keyword);
                        textView.setId(i);
                        textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_gray);
                        textView.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
                        textView.setTextSize(14);
                        textView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams
                                (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                        getLayout_top_search().addView(textView);

                        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                String query = textView.getText().toString();

                            }
                        });

                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Please help.

Comment: Use listview and load the Json array to lsitview . simple way

Comment: @Sanwal Singh How do you want that textview to be.. Like in first image or like the 2nd one.

Comment: I have to design like image 1, if I user listview then it will be come in list format like image 2

Comment: @RethinavelPillai - i like to do  image 1,

Comment: What does getLayout_top_search() return? What is the layout of the Activity to which you adding textview to? Use vertical linearlayout for the container activity

Comment: to look like http://i.stack.imgur.com/mdaEv.png use vertical listview https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView

Comment: @birraa - getLayout_top_search()  - is Linear Layout explain above and textview added into linearlayout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you want is `Flow Layout`

```
<com.wefika.flowlayout.FlowLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="start|top">

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum" />

</com.wefika.flowlayout.FlowLayout>
```

Instead of `LinearLayout` you can use `Flow Layout` Which helps you to add textview in a row. If the row has no enough space it will extend a new row. And then the layout will become like this.

For more Information: Please read [this](https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout) and [this](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1216)

[image]

Please Feel free to ask me.if you are facing any issue.

Comment: If am using this, get error. TextView width comes match_parent. How i set textView width as wrap_content?

Comment: This is error -  java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to com.wefika.flowlayout.FlowLayout$LayoutParams

Comment: @SanwalSingh There is no need to add Layout params. Please delete your textview layout params.

Comment: If I delete this, textview comes with full length.

Comment: @SanwalSingh Try this.. `textView.setLayoutParams(new FlowLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));`

Answer (score 1):

```
TextView tvContent = new TextView(getActivity());
    medicineName.add(tvContent);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams tvParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    tvContent.setLayoutParams(tvParam);
    tvContent.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
    tvContent.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
    tvContent.setText(name);
    tvContent.setTextSize(16);
    layout.addView(tvContent);
```

use this in onPostExecute() method

Answer (score 0):

```
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lLayoutlayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lLayoutlayoutParams.setMargins(0, 8, 8, 8);
    layout.setLayoutParams(lLayoutlayoutParams);
    layout.setPadding((int) (fDimRatio * 8), (int) (fDimRatio * 8),
            (int) (fDimRatio * 8), (int) (fDimRatio * 8));
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);



TextView tvContent = new TextView(getActivity());
    medicineName.add(tvContent);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams tvParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    tvContent.setLayoutParams(tvParam);
    tvContent.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
    tvContent.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
    tvContent.setText(name);
    tvContent.setTextSize(16);
    layout.addView(tvContent);


linearLayout.addView(layout);
```

linearLayout is id of linearlayout in xml

```
linearLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.container);
```

fDimRatio  value is

```
private float fDimRatio = 1.0f; // /xml
```

Comment: What is this - fDimRatio?

Answer (score 0):

If you want like image 1 then change android:orientation="horizontal"